# How to count the number of matching results on a search table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have made a HTML table with a search function. I want to display the matching result amount when searching, and the total amount when search field is blank. I tried with `.length` but it counted all rows included hidden ones.

How can I count only the displayed rows?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/16/)

I'm currently using this code:

```
//testing: count number of results
var rowCount = $('#search-table >tbody >tr').length;
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = rowCount;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use var rowCount = $('#search-table >tbody >tr:visible').length; for getting the displayed records count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the length of only visible tr elements after search. you can use `:visible` or `:not(:hidden)` selector to achieve this:

```
var rowCount = $('#search-table >tbody >tr:visible').length;
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Change your rowCount to something like this:

`var rowCount = $('#search-table >tbody >tr:visible').length;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to only count visible rows:

```
var rowCount = $('#search-table >tbody >tr:visible').length;
```