# jQuery/JS - Count results within DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

I'm fairly noob with JS, so go easy.

I have a simple search form that searches the entire BODY and highlights the search term after a click function. This is working great.  However, I'd like to add the function to return the number of results found (in addition to the in-place highlight function).  EDIT:  Also, the results are not displayed on the page, they are only highlighted by the JS script by design.  So, essentially, I just need a way to display the number of results that are highlighted after the search is performed.

All I could find was how to do this with data that is in a table. However, my data is NOT in a table.

Also, This can't be a "live" search, I need it to fire only after the click event has been fired.

This closest solution I could find was [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675892/how-to-count-the-number-of-matching-results-on-a-search-table) but, this is a live search in a table.

Here is my form so far:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#button').click(function() {
    var searchbox = document.querySelector('#text-search');
    var searchForm = document.querySelector('#search');
  });
});


function highlight() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text-search").value;
  var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
  var e = document.getElementById("body").innerHTML;
  var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = enew;
  var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = newe;
  color = "#f6f";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <div id="search" class="Column">
    <form id="searchForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="highlight(); return false;">
      <input name="text-search" id="text-search" type="text" value="" class="input" placeholder="search & highlight">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
    </form>
    <div class="count">search results: </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <div class="expand">
      data
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**UPDATE**:

I almost found a solution thanks to a JS wizard who was helping me with another issue.  So the code below IS counting the number of results, however, it's adding +1 for every DIV on the page, even if the searched term does not exist in that DIV. So, if my body looked like the example below and I searched TEST, the result would be 5 (2 search terms + 3 DIVs)

Body:

```
<div1>
  test
</div>
<div2>
  test
</div>
<div3>
  hai
</div>
```

JS:

```
function count() {
  var count =
  $("#body span").length;
  $(".count").text(count);
};
```

So, how can I adjust for the number of DIVs?

https://jsfiddle.net/seanvree/mqyxqfgu/

Comment: Add some search html part too in your fiddle link. so that we can check how's it's highlighted

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh  Yeah, I'm trying to do that but it's giving me a weird error, It works on my site, but for some reason not in the jfiddle.

Comment: @SeanVreeland JSFiddle is having an issue with the `POST` for some reason. If you copy your code into a Stack Overflow snippet instead, it will work. (Make sure to add jQuery.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
function count() {
    var count =
        $("#body span").length;
    $(".count").text(count);
    $('.count').append(" occurance(s) of searched term");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be wrapping the matches in a span. You could add a class like "match", and count the spans with class match
 Something like this:

```
var matches= $('span.match').length;
```